Problem with invoke-webrequest and Dropbox
I use Dropbox as online storage for programs I install on client computers.
I use this kind of command to download programs from Dropbox to computers:
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/obxhn33o5y5grr8vs9q0h/AKPbHMNzHAhk6-D7vuOo_CU?rlkey=buytm7fk9ixjwr0yjbxdpzfp1&dl=1" -OutFile "c:\test\download.zip"
and than  expand the archive and install program with powershell script...
Up until end of April this command always worked fine. I first noticed on 30th of April that this command runs into a problem. Download fails more than 50% of downloads. I tested this command on different computers, different internet providers, different countries even, but I get the same problem every time. Tested with one free Dropbox account and one with subscription.
Anybody else experiences the same problem? Anybody has any idea, why download fails?
I was checking traffic with Wireshark and got a lot of packet with errors while downloading, but unfortuantely I don't know how to troubleshoot well with Wireshark.
You can test with above command. It has 10MB test file inside, created with fsutil, if ZIP file is less than  10.247KB it's a fail.
I contacted Dropbox, but they say, they don't expirience any issues on their side.
Regards

What happens when it fails? Is there an error message?

No, it just creates a file, but its 150kB large. My next step is extract the file, but that fales, since it's not a complete file.

I ran the command several times and always retrieved a 10 MiB file. Please edit the question and include the output of $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString().

What’s in the 150kb file? Does it have a zip file header and is just a truncated version of the expected download? If you’re running the script in a corporate environment try opening it in a text editor (notepad / notepad++ / etc) and see if it looks like a html file - it might be a new web proxy your IT department has set up which is intermittently sending you a boilerplate “this page is blocked” html page instead of the actual zip file bytes - I’ve had that before :-S…

This question is not relevant any more.
Before I posted this question I turned to Dropbox. Their initial response was that their services run normally, but later in the day they contacted me and told me that they indeed had a problem on their side and it is now resolved.
I can confirm it is now working properly.
